# How to learn system (Windows) non-proxy hosts in Java

Tags: java, windows, proxy, localhost, system

I'm writting a Java (1.7) application to be running on Windows. The application is accessing additional services running on the **same host** and other ones running in the **Internet.** The application can be run in two environments where in one, proxy settings **must be** specified (there is proxy when accessing the Internet); while in the other environment, the proxy settings **must not be** specified (there is no proxy).

I want the application to be simple and don't want its users bother with specification of the proxy settings on cmd-line (-Dhttp.proxyHost, etc.) - the application should **learn the proxy settings from Windows system settings** (IE / Tools / Internet Properties / Connections / LAN Settings).

I have written a piece of code that is supposed to learn that settings, see below. The trouble is that this piece of code does not identify **localhost**, **127.0.0.1** and **my-computer-name** (where my-computer-name is the name of my computer) as URLs where proxy should be by-passed when being accessed (yes, I do have 'Bypass proxy server for local addresses' checked). As a result, the application tries to **access local services through the proxy which is wrong**.

So far I've found out that one way to teach JVM not to use proxy for 'local addresses' is to list the strings (localhost, 127.0.0.1, my-computer-name) in Proxy Settings / Exceptions (Do not use proxy server for addresses beginning with). Obviously, this is not a good solution as usually no one is listing these strings there (the first check-box is enough for non-Java applications).

Second (trivial) solution would be just to count with these strings in my piece of code and do not use proxy settings for them even when JVM thinks otherwise. I don't think this is a good solution and if this is the only solution, IMHO, there is a defect in JVM.

I've found many resources in the Internet how to learn System **proxy** settings. But how to learn the **non-proxy** settings?

Thanks,
PP

```
public static final String HTTP_PROXY_HOST_KEY = "http.proxyHost";
public static final String HTTPS_PROXY_HOST_KEY = "https.proxyHost";
public static final String HTTP_PROXY_PORT_KEY = "http.proxyPort";
public static final String HTTPS_PROXY_PORT_KEY = "https.proxyPort";
public static final String NO_PROXY_HOSTS_KEY = "http.nonProxyHosts";

// provide list of urls which are to be accessed by this application and return proxy and non-proxy settings
private Properties getSystemProxyConfiguration(String[] urls) {
    log.debug("Getting system proxy");
    Properties properties = new Properties();
    SortedSet<String> nonProxyHosts = new TreeSet<>();
    for (String url : urls) {
        URI uri;
        try {
            uri = new URI(url);
        } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
            throw new IllegalStateException(e);
        }
        InetSocketAddress address = getSystemProxy(uri);
        if (address != null) {
            if (url.toLowerCase().startsWith("https")) {
                properties.put(HTTPS_PROXY_HOST_KEY, address.getHostString());
                properties.put(HTTPS_PROXY_PORT_KEY, ""+address.getPort());
                //todo verify that all previous URLs in this array are using the same proxy
                log.debug("HTTPS proxy: " + address.getHostString() + ":" + address.getPort());
            } else {
                properties.put(HTTP_PROXY_HOST_KEY, address.getHostString());
                properties.put(HTTP_PROXY_PORT_KEY, ""+address.getPort());
                //todo verify that all previous URLs in this array are using the same proxy
                log.debug("HTTP proxy: " + address.getHostString() + ":" + address.getPort());
            }
        } else {  //todo DEFECT -> this does not find the non-proxy hosts (even though specified in IE Internet settings)
            nonProxyHosts.add(uri.getHost());
        }
    }
    if (nonProxyHosts.size() > 0) {
        String nonProxyHostsString = nonProxyHosts.first();
        nonProxyHosts.remove(nonProxyHostsString);
        for (String nonProxyHost : nonProxyHosts) {
            nonProxyHostsString = nonProxyHostsString + "|" + nonProxyHost;
        }
        properties.put(NO_PROXY_HOSTS_KEY, nonProxyHostsString);
        log.debug("Non HTTP(S) proxy hosts: "+nonProxyHostsString);
    } else {
        log.debug("No non HTTP(S) proxy hosts set");
    }
    return properties;
}

private InetSocketAddress getSystemProxy(URI uri) {
    List<Proxy> proxyList;
    proxyList = ProxySelector.getDefault().select(uri);
    if (proxyList != null && proxyList.size() > 0) { //todo DEFECT - this never returns DIRECT proxy for localhost, 127.0.0.1, my-computer-name strings
        Proxy proxy = proxyList.get(0);
        if (proxyList.size() > 1) {
            log.warn("There is more " + proxy.type() + " proxies available. Use "+PROXY_PROPERTIES_FILE_NAME+" to set the right one.");
        }
        InetSocketAddress address = (InetSocketAddress) proxy.address();
        return address;
    }
    return null;
}
```